# Replace non-matching substrings in each element in data.frame R

Tags: r

Seems like a simple question, but it has stumped me for a few hours and sleuthing has been unsuccessful..

I have a large dataframe with elements containing characters "ABCD", etc.

I want to replace the element with NA if the 1st and 3rd substring don't match:

"DAD" "MOM" "BABOON" "SISTER" elements would be left alone (because first and third substrings match, but "CAT" "STEP" "JULIAN" would be set to NA. The length of each element is dynamic but it's always the 1st and 3rd substring i'm interested in.

```
> dput(d)
structure(list(v1 = structure(c(6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("BABOON", 
"BOB", "BOO", "CAR", "CAT", "JULIAN"), class = "factor"), v2 = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("GREEN", "GROW", "LINDA", "MOM", 
"SKY", "TOP"), class = "factor"), v3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("DAD", "GAG", "LOGAN", "LOOK", "SISTER", 
"STAR"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Among other attempts, I feel this is the closest i have gotten:

```
d_with_NAs=d[apply(d,1,function(y) if(substring(d[y],1,1) != substring(d[y],3,3)){y=NA}),]
```

d_with_NAs should look like:

```
v1  v2  v3
NA  MOM NA
BOB NA  DAD
BABOON  NA  SISTER
NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  GAG
NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: It is always best to provide a reproducible example.  Please provide a small example of the `data.frame` and your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 x <- c("DAD", "MOM", "BABOON", "SISTER", "CAT", "STEP", "JULIAN")
 ind <- substr(x, 1, 1) != substr(x, 3, 3)
 x[ind] <- NA
 x
 #[1] "DAD"    "MOM"    "BABOON" "SISTER" NA       NA       NA
```

*edit*

in the context of a `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(apply(dat, 2, FUN = function(x){
 tmp <- rep(NA, length(x))
 ind <- substr(x, 1, 1) == substr(x, 3, 3)
 tmp[ind] <- x[ind]
 tmp
   })
)

#      v1   v2     v3
#1   <NA>  MOM   <NA>
#2    BOB <NA>    DAD
#3 BABOON <NA> SISTER
#4   <NA> <NA>   <NA>
#5   <NA> <NA>    GAG
#6   <NA> <NA>   <NA>
```

or even more succinctly and without type conversion:

```
sapply(dat, FUN = function(x) {x[substr(x, 1, 1) != substr(x, 3, 3)] <- NA; x})
```

Comment: Technically this works. However, it does not appear to scale the DF. Appreciate the response however, it will give me a new avenue

Comment: @K.J.J.K try adding an example of your `df`; otherwise it's impossible to see what you want exactly. i am not sure what you mean by "scaling the DF"

Comment: `ind <- substr(x$v1, 1, 1) != substr(x$v1, 3, 3) ; x$v1[ind] <- NA` works

Answer (score 1):

Just apply stas g's solution to the rows or columns of the data.frame:

```
x <- c("DAD", "MOM", "BABOON", "SISTER", "CAT", "STEP", "JULIAN")
y <- c("BOB", "TITLES", "CACAO", "PREGNANT", "FLIP", "TRINIAN", "COILSPRING")
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
newdf = apply (df, 2, function(x){
   # this bit exactly what stas g said
   ind <- substr(x, 1, 1) != substr(x, 3, 3)
   x[ind] <- NA
   return(x)
})
newdf
```

Comment: a minor comment: your `newdf` output is not a `data.frame` but a `matrix`

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't married to the `data.frame` object you can do this very simply with `matrix` objects and `substr`.

```
mat <- as.matrix(df)
idx <- which(substr(mat, 1, 1) != substr(mat, 3, 3))
mat[idx] <- NA
mat
     v1       v2    v3      
[1,] NA       "MOM" NA      
[2,] "BOB"    NA    "DAD"   
[3,] "BABOON" NA    "SISTER"
[4,] NA       NA    NA      
[5,] NA       NA    "GAG"   
[6,] NA       NA    NA
```

which you could convert back to a `data.frame` if you so wish.

Comment: nice one converting it into a `matrix` and thus avoiding `*apply`